# How to specify actions for auxiliary buttons in AlertifyJS?

Tags: alertifyjs

AlertifyJS has a place to put auxiliary buttons.

I would like for two things to happen when my auxiliary button is clicked

1. The dialog should not close
2. Some function should be run

How do I do these two things?

I can get the notification to show up by passing it as the third parameter, but the dialog disappears. Also, this wouldn't work if I had multiple auxiliary buttons and different functions for each.

Below is my javascript, and [here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuar6au1/).

```
    // Run this function when the auxiliary button is clicked
    // And do not close the dialog
    var helpInfo = function () {
        alertify.notify("help help help");
    };

    var custom = function () {
        if (!alertify.helper) {
            alertify.dialog('helper', function factory() {
                return {
                    setup: function () {
                        return {
                            buttons: [{
                                text: 'Help',
                                scope: 'auxiliary'
                            }],
                            options: {
                                modal: false
                            }
                        };
                    }
                };
            }, false, 'alert');
        }
        alertify.helper('Do you need help?', "hello world", helpInfo);
    };

    custom();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AlertifyJS callbacks will be passed a special `closeEvent` object. To keep the dialog open, your callback should set the cancel property to `true` or simply `return false`.

```
var helpInfo = function (closeEvent) {    
   alertify.notify("help help help");    
   closeEvent.cancel = true;
  //or
  //return false;
};
```

See [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fuar6au1/1/)

Comment: I actually just figured that out and was going to type out a response. I updated the fiddle myself and noticed that it put /2/ in the URL, so I tried /1/ and saw yours. So I figured I'd wait until you posted an answer. :)

Comment: If I have multiple auxiliary buttons, can they each have a different callback or do I have to have a single callback that figures out which button was clicked?

Comment: Since your dialog is based on `alert`, you have one callback and it will be called for all of your buttons. see https://github.com/MohammadYounes/AlertifyJS/blob/master/src/js/alert.js#L84-L91

Comment: The  `closeEvent` also provides another two properties `index` and `button` see http://alertifyjs.com/factory.html

Comment: If you wish to create a new type of dialog with separate callbacks, take a look at the prompt dialog https://github.com/MohammadYounes/AlertifyJS/blob/master/src/js/prompt.js

Comment: Not works in rthe latest version 2022. helpInfo is never called

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional parameter to the `helpInfo` function so you can access the Event object passed along with the event. Now you can prevent it's default action (which would close the dialog).

```
var helpInfo = function (e) {
    alertify.notify("help help help");
    e.preventDefault();
};
```

Comment: Check the console when you do that. It raises an error "undefined is not a function (evaluating 'e.preventDefault()')". You are right that the dialog does not go away, but not in the way you think :)